# In R, after installed a package,' pixmap', Error in file(file, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, warnings, connection

I'm learning R programming, using the book, "The Art of R Programming".
In chapter 3.2.3 Extended Example: Image Manipulation. The author Matloff tries to use a Mount Rushmore gray-scale image to illustrate that the image is stored in matrix. He used a library called pixmap. And I downloaded the package, installed it.

```
> library(pixmap)
> mtrush1 <- read.pnm("mtrush1.pgm")
> mtrush1
Pixmap image
  Type          : pixmapGrey
  Size          : 194x259
  Resolution    : 1x1
  Bounding box  : 0 0 259 194
> plot(mtrush1)
```

This is what the book has written, and I tried to run this, but got the error message,

```
> library(pixmap)
> mtrush1 <- read.pnm("mtrush1.pgm")
Error in file(file, open = "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, open = "rb") :
  cannot open file 'mtrush1.pgm': No such file or directory
starting httpd help server ... done
```

What does this mean? cannot open the connection? And also the mtrush1.pgm does not exist? How should I fix it here? Any help? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

#### Summary:

*Add the argument `cellres=1` to your function call and you should be fine.*

---

#### Answer:

The second error you saw--`Warning message: In rep(cellres, length = 2) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL`--is because you haven't set the **cellres** argument and, as a result, "cellres" assumes its default value (i.e. 'NULL'--hence the warning). For what you're working on, setting the cellres argument to 1 will do the trick (though you can pass in a two-element vector with unequal values and see just how it affects your figure by plotting the resulting object).

**Note:** Though it's a little late to be answering, I figure that since I had the same problem earlier today (and since Google was no help) a response was probably warranted.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the file `mtrush1.pgm` is not in current directory. You should either `setwd` to the directory that contains this file, or specify the complete path in `read.pnm`.

For the file `mtrush1.pgm`, you can download it from http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/

Comment: Thanks, oh, I need to download it first.. I thought it's in the library.  But as I add the complete path, there is a new error here,   
    > mtrush1 <- read.pnm("/Users/bruce/Documents/R          
    programming/mtrush1.pgm")
    Warning message:
    In rep(cellres, length = 2) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be     NULL

Comment: @StayFoolish: yes, if it were in the package, you still need to use the `data()` function to load the dataset into session.

Comment: @StayFoolish: have you tried `read.pnm(file = "/Users/bruce/Documents/R programming/mtrush1.pgm")`?

Comment: :Still the same warning

Comment: @StayFoolish: people got the same warning here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/read-pnm-question-td4662160.html

Answer (score 0):

The file `mtrush1.pgm` and the R scripts from the book "The Art Of R Programming" can be found at [this GitHub site](https://github.com/rickylim19/TheArtOfR).